# In Crookes (roentgen) tube where does electrons come from?

Tags: electromagnetism, x-rays

1. In [Crookes (roentgen) tube](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crookes_tube) X-rays are generated by bombarding metal target by accelerated electrons.
   Where does the electron come from?
2. Are they produced by ionization of residual air or from the electrode some how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from wiki: *Crookes tubes are cold cathode tubes, meaning that they do not have a heated filament in them that releases electrons as the later electronic vacuum tubes usually do. Instead, electrons are generated by the ionization of the residual air by a high DC voltage (from a few kilovolts to about 100 kilovolts) applied between the electrodes, usually by an induction coil (a "Ruhmkorff coil"). The Crookes tubes require a small amount of air in them to function, from about $10^{−6} \to 5 \times 10^{−8}$ atmosphere.*